# Dynamically sending a domain to one of two folders

Tags: apache

Is it possible on an Apache server to send requests to a domain to sita A or site B where siteA and siteB  are sitting in different folders on the server? Ideally I'd like to do  this dynamically, like every tenth request goes to siteB.  Lacking that, changing a configuration parameter somewhere to make the switch would be usable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could script the Apache configuration to change every few minutes and then reload. Not a great solution but do-able. Why would you want to do what you are asking anyway?

Comment: We're putting up a new version of a site and may want to switch users back to he old site if there's a problem.  Or we might want to run just 5% of the domain visitors to the new site and watch the conversion rate, etc. before deciding to run all our traffic to the new site.

Comment: Hmm - I don't know if Apache can do that out of the box. But it would be easy to script it with perl for example. Personally I would either run the new website for a set amount of time then revert to old website and analyse the results / conversion of new site. Or set up the new site on www2.site.com and depending on how your website is set up redirect every 10 visitor to the www2 version using your front end code.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean www2.site.com?

Comment: say your current website was found at www.yoursite.com - set up your new site on www2.yoursite.com